# Stress-energy tensor of Rarita-Schwinger field in algebraic special spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I’m recently working on a calculation of Rarita-Schwinger field on Petrov type N spacetime (e.g. pp waves) with $\Psi_{0}=\Psi_{1}=\Psi_{2}=\Psi_{3}=0$. And I found a paper *”Rarita–Schwinger fields in algebraically special vacuum space‐times”* by G. F. Torres del Castillo which is valid for all vacuum type D (and thus for N) spacetimes:

https://doi.org/10.1063/1.528409

In this paper the RS equation is represented by $\psi^{A}_{\ \ \ BC}$ in spinor basis (see eq. (1)-(3)):

$$\nabla_{A\dot{D}}\psi^{A}_{\ \ \ B\dot{C}}=\nabla_{B\dot{C}}\psi^{A}_{A\dot{D}},$$

And the Rarita-Schwinger field are then represented by a quantity $H$

$$H^{A}_{\ \ BC}\equiv \nabla_{(B}^{\ \ \ \ \dot{D}}\psi^{A}_{\ \ \ \ C)\dot{D}}, H^{A}_{\ \ \dot{B}\dot{C}}\equiv \nabla^{D}_{\ \ \ \ (\dot{B}}\psi^{A}_{\ \ \ \ |D|\dot{C})},$$

With $H$ the RS equation becomes to

$$H_{ABC}=H_{(ABC)},H_{A\dot{B}\dot{C}}=0. $$

After some calculation, this gives a equation of $H_{000}$ (see eq. (10)):

$$[(D-2\epsilon +\overline{\epsilon}-3\rho - \overline{\rho})(\Delta - 3\gamma + \mu)-(\delta -2\beta -\overline{\alpha}-3\tau +\overline{\pi})(\overline{\delta}-3\alpha + \pi)-\Psi_2]H_{000}=0$$

where $\Psi_2$ is the NP-Weyl complex scalar.

And my question is how to recover the ordinary RS field $\psi_{\nu}$ from the one $\psi^{A}_{\ \ \ BC}$ in spinor basis and how to represent the stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ of RS field by $H_{000}$?

Comment: See section 5.8 of "Spinors and Space-time - Vol-I"

Comment: @KP99 Thank you I found these words on p360 that “However for spin 3/2,1/2,... there is no expression for Tab which has the required properties of symmetry and vanishing divergence...” But If so, what we mean by “absorption cross section” when we talk about perturbative test fields of various spins in Kerr background  and Teuklosky equation?

Comment: Where did you get this term : "absorption cross section"?

Comment: @KP99 For example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.06570.pdf page 67 Figure 16 what the “absorption” means here? energy density/flux or squared norm of amplitude?

Comment: @KP99 Do you know how to recover the original field quantities from the H function？

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am actually confused about the notation that you have used here ( for instance the field H can have both combination of indices like $H_{ABC}$ and $H_{AB'C'}$, the former can be a spin 3/2 field while later is a potential) The answer to this question is in page 370 and more about it in the section 5.10 (Exact set of fields)

Comment: @KP99 how to recover the ordinary field quantities in RS equation from these H_{ABC} and \psi_{ABC’} in the article above. p370 don’t mention about their transformation relations.

Comment: @KP99 Neither do section 5.10